# CSS :before :after background color

Tags: css, colors

I want to turn the heart shape black upon click but changing .heart's color won't affect its :before :after selector. Is there any way to do so?

```
.heart {
  background-color: red;
  height: 60px; /*dimension of the square*/
  position: relative;
  top: 40px; /*position from top*/
  transform: rotate(-45deg); /*negative = counter clockwise, put 0 to try*/
  width: 60px; /*dimension of the square*/
  transition: all 1s ease; /*length of animation*/
}

.heart:before,
.heart:after {
  content:""; /*kosong, for it to exist*/
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%; /*perfect round curve*/
  height: 60px; /*dimension of the shape*/
  position: absolute;
  width: 60px; /*dimension of the shape*/
}

.heart:before {
  top: -30px; /*position of the left shape*/
  left: 0; /*remember rotated ACW 45deg*/
}

.heart:after {
  left: 30px; /*position of the right shape*/
  top: 0px; /*remember rotated ACW 45deg*/
}

.heart
    {
        opacity:0.3; /*original state*/
    }
.heart:hover
    {
        opacity:1; /*hover state*/
    }
.heart:active
    {
        opacity:1; /*hover state*/
        background:black;
    }
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please upload a fiddle with both html and css, it will be way easier for us to help you.

Comment: thanks will do next time!

Comment: @AhQuan, they mean you should edit this question to include the additional information they're requesting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to target your pseudo-elements when applying an :active / :hover etc. state as well.

Like so:

```
.heart:active::before,
.heart:active::after {
  background: black;
}
```

Here is a working **[Fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/8zLbe5nd/)**

I also added a transition for your pseudo elements, so that they can fade nicely with the bottom part of the heart.

Answer (score 2):

Simply change the value of the `background` property of the pseudo-elements to [`inherit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/inherit) and it will match the `background`of the parent `.heart` element at all times. This way you don't have to remember to add more rules if you add more colour changes in the future. And it has the added bonus of inheriting the transition from red to black from the parent.

```css
.heart{
  background:#f00;
  height:60px;
  left:30px;
  opacity:.3;
  position:relative;
  top:40px;
  transform:rotate(-45deg);
  transition:background 1s ease,opacity 1s ease;
  width:60px;
}
.heart:hover{
  opacity:1;
}
.heart:active{
  background:#000;
  opacity:1;
}
.heart:before,.heart:after{
  content:"";
  background:inherit;
  border-radius:50%;
  height:60px;
  position:absolute;
  width:60px;
}
.heart:before{
  left:0;
  top:-30px;
}
.heart:after{
  left:30px;
  top:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="heart"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, as mentioned before, **you need to specifically target the before and after pseudo elements**. the way to do this is by adding the following CSS:

```
.element:active::before,
.element:active::after{
  background-color: #000;
}
```

This way you will target the before and after pseudo elements when your element is active. There is a great article [here](https://kolosek.com/css-before-and-after/) explaining the before and after property.